# Do LED and photodiode rise times matter for time-of-flight (TOF) measurement?

Tags: led, measurement, photodiode, time, rise-time

Do I need small rise times of an LED and a photodiode/APD when considering time-of-flight measurement? Given I know rise time of both diodes I am always able to count time of flight by subtracting those times from the final measurement, right?

A sub-question: does a photodiode need a pulse that is longer than its rise time for the pulse to be detected at all?

Comment: Yes of course, if the signal input is only for 5 nano seconds, and your rise time is 10 nano seconds, you will only detect 50% of it! That's terrible for a ToF measurement!

Comment: You may also keep the ToF pulse on long enough that you have definitely received a full 'settled' response from the APD. But all you need is to trigger the rising edge of the input, with reference to the rising edge of the output, and the difference in time divide by 2 (return time) and multiplied by the speed of light is your distance

Answer (score 1):

Generally the faster the rise time the more resolution you will be able to achieve as there will be less ambiguity on the receive edge.  It also does not make sense to use a detector that is significantly slower than the transmitter as this will waste the transmit rise time.  Note that the rise time is the important factor here, the pulse length does not really matter so long as it is long enough to reliably detect.  The length may be constrained by the duty cycle of the transmitter, however.  Some transmitters are pulse-mode devices which can emit a very powerful burst of light (as in a several watt laser) for a few ns, but then need to recover for several us before another pulse can be generated.

It's not so much the rise time that you need to characterise; it's the delay.  The rise time just needs to be fast enough to get an accurate measurement, then you need to calibrate out all of the delays.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Photodiode (PD) with short pulse width.  You will still see a small signal.
It's width will be determined by the PD response time.
Thinking in the frequency domain, a short light pulse means you are beyond the 3dB point of the PD, and can expect reduced amplitude.